# NgTable get total of data

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

How can i return the total of all data .?(length of data which is shown in ngTable)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0RI5kpu1xC8KIquHeB0?p=preview)

```
  <pre>Total DATA: ...??</pre>
```

Comment: What dou you mean by DATA? Money, age? We need more info...

Comment: @Z0K4 number of lines

Comment: @Z0K4 in this example i want to return Total Data: 15

Comment: why you don;t put data in scope, do `$scope.data` instead of `var data` so that on UI you could to `{{data.length}}`

Comment: Your table has 17 lines. You can read size of the table by exposing your table data to the scope. So, a solution is to add in your app.js `$scope.tableData = data;` and in your html `{{tableData.length}}` Like this: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/lnt7l99a3EeMkD3hpaYE?p=preview)

Comment: @Z0K4 thats what i said to him :p

Comment: @pankajparkar Didn't see your comment. Looks like you beat me by couple of seconds. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the current length of the data you need to put data in some scope variable so that it would easily accessible on HTML, currently you have stored data in `var data` so you need to do `$scope.data = data` & on UI you need to use interpolation directive to gets its length

```
<pre>Total DATA: ...{{data.length}}</pre>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tsM4pcaAwiSJFUckuFCx?p=preview)